# Entity not using specified sequence while saving in JPA for postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I want to use custom sequence(`orderId_seq`) while saving my entity instead of default one(`hibernate_sequence`) in postgres-9.5.

My entity is :

```
 @Entity
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "orderId_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="orderId_generator", sequenceName = "orderId_seq")
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long orderId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid",nullable = false)
    @Type(type="pg-uuid")
    private UUID userId;

    private String comments;

    private String assignedTo;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private OrderStatus status;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false, 
     columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP with time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private Timestamp orderedDate;

  //getters and setters
```

when I save this entity to the database. It is generating some random number for `orderId` instead of using `orderId_seq`.

When I check the order entity in debug mode before saving it is null but after saving it is creating some random number not even using `hibernate_sequence`.

And when I use `show_sql=true` option in hibernate it is even showing the following statement in the console :

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('orderId_seq')
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: [link](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/seq-generator/)

Comment: You said you want to use your sequence "orderId_seq" and the SQL shows you that it is. And your problem is ? You said yourself it is not using "hibernate_sequence", and you didn't want it to use that ...

Comment: The problem is even though it is showing in the sql when i see the record in the database it inserts some random value not the sequence next value.

Comment: Using SpringBoot 1.5.6, Postgres 9.4  and using the following which is quite similar to yours.  
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "My_Id_Gen", sequenceName = "SEQ_MY_TBL_PK")
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "My_Id_Gen")
 private Long id; 
 
 works fine and uses values from the sequence to populate the PK.
 'hibernate_sequence' is created but not used in the above case.